# Add specific text when there's no text in it

Tags: php, html

This is my code:

```
<?php if($tagline != "")
   echo $tagline;
   else 
    echo "Welcome to my Site!";
?>
```

For some reason, when the tagline is empty, it doesn't add the text.

Comment: Well, we hardly can help with that... I suggest you dump the value of `$tagline`. Maybe it is not empty, but something like `"     "`? Or `&nbsp;`?

Comment: Make sure the $tagline string is empty with the native PHP function: empty ($tagline)

Comment: Make sure to use brackets in your code as well. That code won't function one bit.

Comment: What do you meant by empty? In order for it to echo "Welcome to my Site!", then `$tagline` must be either not set, `null`, `0`, `false`, or `''`. If you don't see the text, then `$tagline` must be something other than one of those things.

Comment: @BlakeConnally While using brackets is a good practice, that code absolutely will function without them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try another approach for the check of the $tagline variable

```
if (strlen(trim($tagline)) > 0) {
    echo $tagline;
} else {
    echo "Welcome to my Site!";
}
```

or something that you would use in a couple of years :) :

```
echo (strlen(trim($tagline)) > 0) ? $tagline : "Welcome to my Site!";
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. That's definitely a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display a text if a given variable is empty you can use directly [empty() method in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) like this:

```
    <?php 
    if(!empty($tagline)){
       echo $tagline;
    } else {
        echo "Welcome to my Site!";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: are you sure `empty("  ")` will return true?